# MongoDB setup for on-demand env

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

sharing the setting of robo3t in order to connect to an on-demand env:

[Change to your env CONFIG_HOST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UAY6.png)

[Connect to zazma db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqOaY.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.